# How to handle exception after call commit() or flush()

Tags: java, jpa, exception

Is there a "best-practice"-way of handling PersistenceExceptions after a commit() or flush() ?

The way I understand it, after a PersistenceException, the transaction is going to be rolled back in any case, so what´s the best way to do it : do I try to merge() and commit() again in the catch-block, or do i just log a warning/error and tell the user to try again? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I try to merge() and commit() again in the catch-block,

That is unlikely to work.  Certainly it won't work in the context of the current transaction.

> or do i just log a warning/error and tell the user to try again?

Certainly log an error/warning.  Whether you tell the user to try again, or not depends on the *reason* that the commit failed.  If you don't have some insight into the *probable* cause, suggesting that the user should try again is ... dubious.

> Or something else entirely?

If you can accurately diagnose the cause of the exception (in some cases at least), you could use that to decide what to do.  But it could get complicated.  Basically, you need to distinguish cases where the root cause is:

- bad user input,
- stale data or the like caused by some other transaction committing, or
- a bug in the the application, deadlock, etc where retrying is unwise.

(The chances are that some users will retry anyway ... no matter what the application suggests.)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you typically can do, is to log the problem and inform user about it.
As you already mentioned, the on-going transaction is marked as rollback-only. So any further DB changes are therefore meaningless.

Also make that that you're using XA transaction (distributed transaction), ie. configure everything to use JTA transaction manager and therefore participate in one and only one transaction. This is really required if you're using more than one transaction-aware resource (two databases, db + jms, etc.).